# Sum of Dirichlet Kernels

Tags: trigonometry

I need to sum up several Dirichlet kernels. To do this, I would like to have a compact formula for 
$$
\sum_{n=-N}^N \sin(2nx+\xi)
$$ where $x,\xi \in \mathbb R$. The final result should look like something similar to a product of two Dirichlet Kernels.

To be more precise: I want to sum up 
$$
\sum_{n=-N}^N \sin( (M+n)2\phi )
$$ for $M \geq N$ a natural number and $\phi \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=-N}^N \sin(2(n+M)\phi)&=\sin(2M\phi)\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(2n\phi)\right)\\\\
&=\sin(2M\phi)\left(1+2\text{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \left(e^{i2\phi}\right)^n\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sin(2M\phi)\left(1+2\text{Re}\left(\frac{e^{i2\phi}-e^{i2(N+1)\phi}}{1-e^{i2\phi}}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sin(2M\phi)\left(1+2\frac{\cos((N+1)\phi)\sin(N\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(2M\phi)\sin((2N+1)\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}
\end{align}$$